# How to mark a CSS class as deprecated

Tags: html, css, refactoring, deprecated, collaboration

is there a (good) way to mark a CSS class as deprecated?

The idea is during refactoring, when you create new clean classes, but want to update your site gradually so you have to keep both the old and new class for some time, but you would like other to only use the new class for new features.

A comment in the class definition is a first step, but only helps when you actually check the class implementation, it doesn't help when the class usage is just copied from somewhere else.

What I'm looking for is rather something that would be displayed in the IDE or where a linter could throw a warning

Comment: Maybe using a class in body and conditionally link the styles?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add comment to the old class (for example: /* duplicate, new class created*/, so that you know what to delete after you have new class.

Comment: Off course, I did that already... But that requires for every developer that uses the class to actually go and look at the file.
It doesn't help when the class usage is just copied from somewhere else.

What I'm looking for is rather something that would be displayed in the IDE or where a linter could throw a warning

Answer (score -1):

You can put messages inside your css rulesets like so:

```
.center {
  text-align: "center";
  --deprecated: "WARNING: Use .other-class instead";
}
```

This way developers and users can see the message directly in their browsers and take action

Comment: Wouldn't work for my use case since I want to gradually switch to the new class.
This would however break every usage of the old one

Comment: This would not break the usage of the old one at all. This message would appear when someone inspects their HTML in the browser.

Comment: You're right... So it's already better than a comment, but still not visible in IDE...
Would there be a way to catch usage of a class that has this property set with eslint?

Comment: You shouldn't do that as it doesn't help with telling the IDE a class is deprecated. Moreover, --syntax is used for Custom Properties in CSS.

Comment: as long as there's no `--deprecated` var in your project's CSS, it's a clever idea indeed.